# JSP Quiz not going to the next question on click of Next button

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp, button

I am building a quiz in a JSP that displays one question at a time with four answers, all of which are obtained from a MySQL database. Currently, with the below code, the page is able to display the first question and allow the user to submit an answer via a radio button. However, on clicking the 'Next' button, the page refreshes to still display question one. I want it to display the next question, so question two, then three, and so on. How do I do this?

If possible, could someone write the code for me rather than just explain it?

Also, I am very much aware using scriptlets is not a good thing to do, however, I am nowhere near as advanced enough to be able to do otherwise. Apologies for the mess of code, I had to rush this project as I only had a week to complete it.

```
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
Statement st = null;

String action;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int score = 0;
int count = 0;
int QID = 1;


try {
    Class.forName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver");
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mariadb://ebs-db.eastbarnetschool.com//DETAILS);
    System.out.println("Connection made");


    CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call GetQuestionTitle(?, ?)}");
        stmt.setInt(1, QID); 
        stmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        stmt.execute();
        String description = stmt.getString(2);
        System.out.println(description);
%>
<% 

    CallableStatement answer1 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer1(?, ?)}");
        answer1.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer1.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer1.execute();
        String answerOne = answer1.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerOne);

    CallableStatement answer2 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer2(?, ?)}");
        answer2.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer2.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer2.execute();
        String answerTwo = answer2.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerTwo);

    CallableStatement answer3 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer3(?, ?)}");
        answer3.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer3.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer3.execute();
        String answerThree = answer3.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerThree);

    CallableStatement answer4 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetAnswer4(?, ?)}");
        answer4.setInt(1, QID); 
        answer4.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        answer4.execute();
        String answerFour = answer4.getString(2);
        System.out.println(answerFour);

%>
<%
String chosenAnswer=" ";
if(request.getParameter("button")!=null)
{
chosenAnswer=request.getParameter("button").toString();
}

CallableStatement stmt2 = conn.prepareCall("{call GetCorrectAnswer(?, ?)}");
    stmt2.setInt(1, QID); 
    stmt2.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
    stmt2.execute();
    String CorrectDescription = stmt2.getString(2);
    System.out.println("\nCorrect Answer: " + CorrectDescription);

%> 
<br>
<form name="Quiz" method="get" action='Quiz.jsp'>
<br>
<center>
<table border="1" width="500px" bgcolor="lightblue" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<h1 align="center"><font color="white" face="arial">Quiz</font></h1>
<table border="0" width="500px" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="6">
<tr>
<td width="50%"><font color="steelblue" face="arial" size=4><span style="font-weight:normal"> QUESTION <%=QID%></span></font></td>
<tr>
<td width="100%"><font color="black" face="arial" size=4><span style="font-weight:normal"><%=description%></span></font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td>        
1: <input type="radio" name="button" value= "<%=answerOne%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerOne%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
2: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerTwo%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerTwo%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
3: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerThree%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerThree%></font></td>
    <tr>
    <td>
4: <input type="radio" name="button" value="<%=answerFour%>" /><font face="arial" size=3><%=answerFour%></font></td>
<tr><td><center>

<%
%>


<input type="submit" value="Next" name="next">

</center></td></tr> 
</table>    
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>

<%
if(request.getParameterValues("button") != null) {
       if(chosenAnswer.equals(CorrectDescription)) {
           score = score + 1;
%>
<h4 align="center"><font color="green" face="arial">You got Question <%=QID-1%> correct!</font></h4>
<%
}   
       else{
%>
<h4 align="center"><font color="red" face="arial">You got Question <%=QID-1%> incorrect!</font></h4>
<%  
    }   
    }
%>
<input name="QID" type="HIDDEN" value="<%=QID+1%>" id="thisField">
</form>
<% 
} catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e.getMessage());

} finally {
if (rs != null) rs.close();
if (st != null) st.close();
if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
```

Comment: What is `ONCLICK = <%=QID=QID+1%>>` supposed to do? Looks like you are mixing the idea of server and client side scripting here

Comment: Oh that was a redundant piece of code I forgot to remove, thanks.

Comment: You set `int QID = 1;` every time you call the code if your code above is `Quiz.jsp`

Comment: So are you suggesting a loop? I set QID as 1 because that is where the quiz starts from.

Comment: You need to read QID from the request  - and only set it if it is the first time into the code (loading page for the first time)

Comment: Okay so how do I do that then?

Comment: I assume (not doing any JSP myself): `int QID=1;
if(request.getParameter("QUI")!=null)
{
QID=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("QUI"));
}`

Comment: See my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume (not doing any JSP myself)

1. Remove `ONCLICK = <%=QID=QID+1%>>` since it does nothing useful
2. Change `int QID=1` to

---

```
int QID=1; 
if(request.getParameter("QID")!=null) {   
  QID=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("QID"));
}
```

This will let the

```
<input name="QID" type="HIDDEN" value="<%=QID+1%>" id="thisField">
```

do the job

You will need code to not go over the number of questions available

Comment: While this worked, I do have some separate problems now, but thank you for this.